# How can I design a table with greater than in where statement and ordering to avoid filesort?

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I have a list of documents that I store along with creation date and rank:

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rank` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_combo` (`category_id` ASC, `created_at` ASC, `rank` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I would like to get a list of 10 documents that belong to category 30, were created_at is after certain point in time and order it by rank:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    id
FROM
    docs.document
WHERE
    category_id = 30
    AND created_at > 1592862179
ORDER BY
    rank
LIMIT 10
```

It's not surprising that this query has to use filesort:

```
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                    |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | document | ref  | idx_combo     | idx_combo | 4       | const | 19596 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

If the table is large and I have many records for many years and want to retrieve data for specific date range, filesort becomes performance issue. I would like to be able to retrieve results directly from the index. Is there a way to redesign the table, index or the select query for mysql to only use the index for retrieval and avoid temp tables or filesort?

Comment: Add `id` to this index - it will become covering for your query which will improve performance avoiding access to the table body. Check what condition is more selective, and if the condition by `created_at`, then put it first in the index expression.

Comment: @Akina innodb already adds id to secondary index. That's not what question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done.

To achieve the goal, you would need a 2-dimensional index.  Such does not exist.

```
WHERE
    category_id = 30
    AND created_at > 1592862179
```

That much is handled nicely with `INDEX(category_id, created_at)`.  But adding anything onto the end of the index definition will not benefit you

The only way to get the index to be *also* useful for the `ORDER BY` is to have `ORDER BY created_at` (either `ASC` or `DESC`).  At that point, it can stop after 10 rows (because of `LIMIT 10`).

More on indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to find an alternative.